# Как узнать время выполнения laravel 5.6

Tags: php, php7, laravel-5.6

Как узнать время выполнения приложения laravel 5.6?

ранее работал такой метод в \public\index.php добавить

```
$start = microtime(true);
```

а в конец этого файлы

```
$time = microtime(true) - $start;
printf('Скрипт выполнялся %.4F сек.', $time);
```

теперь это не работает 
после $response->send(); больше на экран нечего не выводиться, подозриваю там теперь die()

x-debug не придлагайте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы пробовал смотреть в сторону `register_shutdown_function()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) если есть подозрение, что приложение выходит не в конце index.php, а вообще в laravel есть замечательный debugbar с профайлером и прочими плюшками.

Comment: спасибо, а можете дать ссылку на debugbar с профайлером?

Answer (score 0):

У меня

```
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
$time_end = microtime(true);
$time = $time_end - LARAVEL_START;
printf('Скрипт выполнялся %.4F сек.', $time);
dump($time);
```

Выдержка из index.php

Скрипт выполнялся 0.1740 сек.
0.17401003837585

Все работает....